# Get the Latitude,Longitude Points Every 10 meters ,between the Two different Locations in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, latitude-longitude

1. The Points between **A(Home)----> B(Office)**.
2. i already know the Latitude and Longitude of the Home and Office, i drawn the Path Between the Two Locations in the Map
3. **My need**:

   **Get the Latitude and Longitudes of Each 10 meter ,Between the My Home to Office using any Way**.

Note: but we are not travelling.

Please help me Possible ways to Achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `SphericalUtil.computeHeading` and `SphericalUtil.computeOffset` methods from the [Google Maps API utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/).

First, you need to compute the heading from A (home) to B (Office). You can do it like this:

```
double heading = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(home, office);
```

Having `home` and `office` defined like this:

```
LatLng home;
LatLng office;
```

Once you have the heading, you can compute the offset iterating to get a point that lies 10, 20, 30, ... meters from your home towards your office.

For example, to get a point that is 10 meters from your home towards your office:

```
LatLng point10meters = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(home, 10, heading);
```

Comment: thank you Friend :),  here , LatLng home and Latlng Office is Having the Locations Right?

Comment: Yes, locations (latitude/longitude) in WGS84

Comment: Ok,For Example from my home to Office 100 meters ,that Point10meters variable will get 10 different Locations?

Comment: No, `point10meters` will be one point 10 meters from your home pointint towards your office. You will need to compute the distance and iterate to get more points (20, 30, ... meters)

Comment: Ok iam trying .. Friend :) Thanks.

Comment: sphericalUtil is can't resolve symbol in android Studio.

Comment: You need to configure the Google Maps API Utility Library for your project: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/